# Not able to bind port 1131 on Window7 with AVD

Tags: java, android, windows-7, httpserver

I am using the following java code in Android AVD on Windows7 to create my server with serverPort = 1131;

```
            try {
                    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort);

                    serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);

                    while(isRunning){
                            try {
                                    final Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

                                    DefaultHttpServerConnection serverConnection = new DefaultHttpServerConnection();

                                    serverConnection.bind(socket, new BasicHttpParams());

                                    httpService.handleRequest(serverConnection, httpContext);

                                    serverConnection.shutdown();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (HttpException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }

                    serverSocket.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

I get the following exception :-

```
    01-18 06:30:03.381: W/System.err(1494): java.net.BindException: bind failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

The firewall on my machine is off & I have added special rules for that as well.
Do I need to do something special for running server on AVD on Window7?

Kindly help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following on the MSDN site (search the site for "bind" and "EACCES"):

> WSAEACCES - 10013
>
> Permission denied.
>
> An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. An example is using a broadcast address for sendto
>   without broadcast permission being set using setsockopt(SO_BROADCAST).
>
> Another possible reason for the WSAEACCES error is that when the bind function is called (on Windows NT 4.0 with SP4 and later),
>   another application, service, or kernel mode driver is bound to the
>   same address with exclusive access. Such exclusive access is a new
>   feature of Windows NT 4.0 with SP4 and later, and is implemented by
>   using the SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE option.

Thus, if we assume that the JVM native libraries map `WSAEACCES` to this exception, there are two obvious possible explanations:

- This is a permissions-based thing.  ADV doesn't have permission to bind to that port.
- Some other application has already bound to the port with the SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE socket option.

IMO, either explanation is plausible.  (Or it could be something else ...)

Comment: Although, Initially also (by my exp of Linux), I thought it to be some  issue related to process running on the same port. Thanks Stephen for endorsing the same. I changed my port to 8888, now I am not getting that error.